# Test pollution in unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have 2 functions,  `apply_rule` and `match`. Each is defined independently - they don't belong to any class.

`match` takes two required paramters, and an optional parameter, called `pairs`. It defaults to an empty dictionary. Below is the code for `apply_rule` and for `match`. Note that `match` is called, and the optional parameter `pairs` isn't specified.

```
def apply_rule(pat, rule):
  if not isrule(rule):
    return "Not a valid rule"

  subs = match(lhs(rule), pat)
  if subs == {}:
    return pat
  else:
    return substitute(rhs(rule), subs)


def match(pat, lst, pairs={}):
  if pat == [] and lst == []:
    return pairs
  elif isvariable(pat[0]):
    if pat[0] not in pairs.keys():
      pairs[pat[0]] = lst[0]
    elif pat[0] in pairs.keys() and lst[0] != pairs[pat[0]]:
      return False
  elif pat[0] != lst[0]:
    return False
  return match(pat[1:], lst[1:], pairs)
```

Right now, the unittest for `match` fails, because it "remembers" `pairs`, as defined in the test for `apply_rule`.

However, if I change the 3rd line in `apply_rule` to `subs = match(lhs(rule), pat, {})`then the tests pass. **Do you know why?** As far as I can tell, there shouldn't be any way that `match` remembers the value of `pairs` from when it was called in other tests.

Below are the unit tests, for reference.

```
def test_match(self):
    self.assertEqual({}, match(['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']))

    self.assertEqual(self.dict_with_x, match(['a', '_X', 'c'], ['a', '5', 'c']))
    self.assertEqual(self.dict_with_x, match(self.pat_with_xx, self.list_with_55))

    self.assertEqual(self.dict_with_xy, match(self.pat_with_xy, self.list_with_5hi))

    self.assertFalse(match(self.pat_with_xx, ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']))
    self.assertFalse(match(['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'd']))

def test_apply_and_firerule(self):
    pattern1 = "my mother thinks I am fat".split(' ')
    expected = "do you think you are fat ?".split(' ')
    self.assertEqual(apply_rule(pattern1, self.r1), expected)
```

And the failure message...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pattern_matcher_tests.py", line 65, in test_match
    self.assertEqual({}, match(['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']))
AssertionError: {} != {'_Y': 'fat', '_X': 'mother'}
- {}
+ {'_X': 'mother', '_Y': 'fat'}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument
http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from [effbot](http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm)

> Why does this happen? #
>
> Default parameter values are always evaluated when, and only when, the
>   “def” statement they belong to is executed; see:
>
> http://docs.python.org/ref/function.html
>
> for the relevant section in the Language Reference.
>
> What to do instead? #
>
> The workaround is, as others have mentioned, to use a placeholder
>   value instead of modifying the default value. None is a common value:

Comment: Awesome, I hadn't even considered that it was a Python thing, and not a unittest thing

Comment: `None` is my go-to value.